# R : how to append data frames in a list?

Tags: r

i am trying to produce data frames using for loop.
How can i append these data frames to a list and then check if any frame is empty or not ?
I would like to remove the data frames with empty rows from the list.

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You should use `lapply` here without using a `for` loop. The advantages are:

- You want to create a list of data.frame and lapply create a list
- You do the job once , no need to do 2 loops.

Somethinkg like :

```
lapply(seq_len(nbr_df),function(x)
          {
    ## code to create you data.frame dt
    ## dt = data.frame(...)
    if(nrow(dt)>0) dt
})
```

#### second option: data.frames already created in separate variables:

We assume that your variable have a certain pattern, say patt:

```
 lapply(mget(ls(pattern=patt)),function(x)if(nrow(x)>0)x)
```

Comment: Hi, got the following error while running this code  :                               Error: unexpected ')' in:
"if(nrow(transformed)>0) transformed
})"

Answer (score 0):

To append to a list you can

```
Your_list= list()
for(i in numbOfPosibleDF){
 k <- data.frame()
 if(nrow(k)!=0){
  Your_list[paste0(df,i)] = k
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just add valid data frames to the list instead of removing them afterwards. If you want or need to use a for-loop (instead of `lapply` function), you may use following:

```
# init list
list.of.df <- list()
# start your loop to
# create data frame etc.
# ....
df <- data.frame(1,2)
# add to list
if (!is.null(df) && nrow(df)>0) list.of.df[[length(list.of.df)+1]] <- df
# ... end of loop here.
```

Comment: Hi Daniel,                                                               The real problem is, since frames are being produced in a loop. an empty data frame is terminating my loop. When I test for the validity and try to proceed with the next iteration , I get new sets of errors.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone finding this otherwise dead-end page by its title, the way to concatenate consistently formatted data.frames that are items of a list is with plyr:

```
rbind.fill.matrix(lst)
```

Comment: firstly, this answer is incorrect.                                                      secondly, it does not take care of any requirements specified.      and lastly, its the title, not the overview where entire problem can be explained. Obviously there lies a chance for ambiguity.

Comment: Then you might want to rename it 'append data frames **to** a list'. More importantly, please see the [guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) on how to use SO. You should accept (tick) the best answer to close your question.  It's also good practice to (a) demonstrate and describe how you have already tried to resolve the problem, and (b) provide a reproducible example of how it fails, as this (c) helps reduce the risk of ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give a better picture of the scenario :

the frames may or may not have same number of columns/rows.

the data frames are dynamically produced using a for loop.

the frames have all data types: numeric , factor, character.